# C - Initializing a global array in a function

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I have an array that i want to make global, and i want to initialize in a function call.
I want to first declare it without knowing it's size:

```
char str[];
```

and later initialize it:

```
str = char[size];
```

How can i do this?
I'm very new to c and perhaps I'm going completely the wrong way here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to do it is with `malloc`.  First declare just a pointer:

```
char *str;
```

Then in the init function you `malloc` it:

```
str = malloc(sizeof(*str) * size_of_array);
```

This allocates `size_of_array` elements of the size that `str` points to (`char` in this case).

You should check if the allocation failed:

```
if (str == NULL) {
    // allocation failed
    // handle the error
}
```

Normally you have to make sure you `free` this allocated memory when you're done with it.  However, in this case `str` is global, so it never goes out of scope, and the memory will be `free`d when the program ends.

Comment: In C you shouldn't really cast the result of malloc - you only really need to do that in C++ - it should be avoided in C as it can mask otherwise helpful warnings.

Comment: If you want to be general, use `sizeof (*str)`, so you don't have to repeat the type name.  Furthermore, in C you should not cast the result of malloc.

Answer (score 3):

Make your global array declaration look like this:

```
char *str = NULL;
```

Then in your initialisation function do something like this:

```
void init(int size)
{
    ...
    str = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    ...
}
```

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.  If you want to write code that works with any type, use `sizeof (*str)`.

Comment: @Ben: true, but it's a good habit to include the `sizeof` regardless of the type. I'm well aware of the arguments in favour of `sizeof(*str)` but I still prefer `sizeof(char)` in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* str;

str = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
```

You can skip the `*sizeof(char)` since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

Don't forget to deallocate the memory using `free`

Comment: If you want to be general, use `sizeof (*str)`, so you don't have to repeat the type name.  Furthermore, in C you should not cast the result of malloc.

Comment: In C you shouldn't really cast the result of malloc - you only really need to do that in C++ - it should be avoided in C as it can mask otherwise helpful warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `char* str;` instead of an array. Then, allocate the required amount of memory using malloc or calloc and do the initialization in the function call itself.